# Qt heap fragmentation - can QObjects be placed in a memory pool?

Tags: c++, qt, memory-management

I have a Qt app where a large amount of `QObject`s in a list is frequently allocated and deleted as the list is updated.

With time the heap becomes heavily fragmented and the memory usage grows.

I would usually make an object pool where they are allocated contiguously in a large chunk, however this isn't possible with `QObject`.

Each `QObject` must be allocated separately which is a problem for performance. What's even worse is that there is an object hierarchy, so parents delete their children and I have no access to the delete calls, so I can't just write `MyPool->Free(obj)`;

Unless I overload the `new` and `delete` operators?

Comment: How sure are you that `QObject` deletion is the cause of significant memory fragmentation?  Normal memory management is pretty good about avoiding that kind of fragmentation.  It takes a fairly strange pattern of allocation and deallocation to cause serious fragmentation with ordinary objects.  Then it takes a very good understanding of the deallocation pattern to do better with a pool.  But if you think you **can** do better with a pool, obviously overload `new` and `delete`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not going to help much. To preserve binary compatibility, `QObject` uses the PIMPL idiom. A `QObject` is pretty much like this:

```
class QObject {
    QObjectData *d;
};
```

And `sizeof(QObject) == sizeof(void *)`. The actual allocation of the d-pointer has a "sensible" size (and will trigger further allocations) and that's almost totally out of your control unless you're willing to do massive hacks...

Comment: Why can't you overload `new` and `delete` for `QObjectData`?

Comment: That's the part of "massive hacks". Requires modifications to Qt.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty much, if you have case, where you need use pool architecture, you shouldn't use Qt's hierarchy. Use appropriate, effective containers.
If it's case where you *need* that to manage Qt object, mate your pool and structures you allocate in it with preallocated pool of objects you need work with.
To add insult to injury in some cases QT *copies* objects into insides of their containers without our knowledge, while in other cases it only stores pointers. I'd say, Qt isn't a memory management-friendly framework.